# Multiple Adjectives in an X-Bar Tree

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, adjectives, x-bar-theory

I'm having some trouble integrating phrases with multiple adjectives into x-bar trees. Based on what I can understand from the textbook, I would get something like this (apologies for the verb triangle):
[image]

But that doesn't seem right to me. I rearranged the sentence and got this:
[image]

Which makes me think there's a phantom conjunction I'm missing in the first construction. Could someone point me in the right direction (or tell me if I'm completely and utterly wrong)?

Comment: Which textbook are you using? One of the main problems with your first tree is that you have X^0 level categories occupying specifier positions, whereas in classical X-bar theory, specifier positions are reserved for phrasal categories. Another problem with the initial tree is that you're treating the APs as the specifier of N, and the determiner is adjoined to NP. The determiner should be a specifier, whereas the APs should be adjoined, probably at the N' level.

Comment: I'm using the second edition of Carnie's Syntax while I wait for the third ed. to arrive in the mail. It's possible the I haven't gotten to the point where he's told us why the way we've been doing things is wrong or that I've misunderstood it entirely.

Comment: Also, when you say the APs should be adjoined at the N' level, do you mean something like this:

Comment: ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fA6jf.png

Comment: No - there you have an NP with two specifiers. An adjunct is defined formally as some element whose mother and sister have the same category label. Like this: http://ironcreek.net/phpsyntaxtree/stgraph.png.php?

Comment: I'm afraid that image isn't loading - do you have an alternate link?

Comment: Oops! Sorry. Here: http://i.imgur.com/UcucC0H.png

Comment: ![enter image description here][1]
I realized that I also made a typo in the first tree, which probably didn't help matters. Would this be more like it?

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gp7A3.png

Comment: Yes! I can't remember *exactly* how Carnie does things, but that's more like the standard treatment. The crucial part is that the adjectives are both adjoined.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about homework.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about help with particular syntax trees.